# eslint not taking filename from argument in an npm script

Tags: node.js, eslint, npm-scripts

I have written an npm script for eslint, which reads glob patterns for input files (to eslint) from a file names files.txt and invokes eslint with these inputs one by one in a loop:

```
"eslint": "while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js $line; done < files.txt"
```

`files.txt` looks like :

```
"server.js"
"config/**/*.js"
"modules/*/server/**/*.js"
"modules/core/client/app/config.js"
"modules/core/client/app/init.js"
"modules/*/client/*.js"
"modules/*/client/**/*.js"
```

When I run : `npm run eslint`
this is what I get on the terminal:

```
"server.js"
"config/**/*.js"
"modules/*/server/**/*.js"
"modules/core/client/app/config.js"
"modules/core/client/app/init.js"
"modules/*/client/*.js"
"modules/*/client/**/*.js"
```

while if I run `./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js "config/**/*.js"` on the terminal, then it runs properly and prints out the linting warning and errors on stdout.

I am not able to understand why eslint is not running from the script despite giving it the input file glob pattern.

Comment: Just use `standard` and be done with it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @ralphtheninja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Omitting the double quotes in `file.txt` resolves the issue when running via a bash shell.

The content of `file.txt` should read as follows instead:

```
server.js
config/**/*.js
modules/*/server/**/*.js
modules/core/client/app/config.js
modules/core/client/app/init.js
modules/*/client/*.js
modules/*/client/**/*.js
```

Now when you run; `npm run eslint`, the files matching each glob pattern will be linted and any linting warnings/errors will be printed to `stdout`.

**Further explanation:**

When you run the command; `./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js "config/**/*.js"` via the terminal it was successful because the double quotes are actually being removed by the time `eslint` executes.

However, when the double quotes existed in `file.txt` they were being preserved hence why no files were being linted.

**Cross platform:**

As you probably already know... The bash syntax that you are utilizing in your [npm-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) is not transportable. I.e. It will only run successfully via a bash shell and not across platforms.

To ensure cross-platform support I recommend just utilizing eslint's *standard* [CLI/options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface) *(as per @ralphtheninja comment)*.

However, that being said, if you must read the globbing patterns from a separate `files.txt` *(and cross-platform support is a requirement)* then perhaps writing a node utility script to handle that logic is a better approach. The node script which encapsulates that logic can then be invoked via your `npm-script`.